# Dynamic import of font-family by user using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, fonts, font-face

the case i have is the user to be able to upload a custom font which i can use for text in canvas (currently in the same component, but i can change that if its necessary), but currently im not able to make that change because all i was able to find is like when the user add the font from url and select its name then at submit i fire event which calls loadFont bellow:

```
`loadFont() {
    const fontFace = new FontFace('customFont', `url(${this.fontLink})`);
    fontFace.load().then(loadedFont => {
      document.fonts.add(loadedFont);
    });
}`
```

the `document.fonts.add()` function throw error "Property 'add' does not exist on type 'FontFaceSet'."

also i've imported a custom font in the assets, which is working okay but i still needed to import it in the css file

```
`@font-face {
  font-family: handwrite1;
  src: url('./assets/fonts/handwrite1.ttf') format('truetype');
}`
```

but if its dynamic im not sure how i can do that, also there might be more than one fonts which the user wants to import in the app

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What you are attempting to do is screaming "SECURITY ISSUE!!" at me. It might be possible, but is it really necessary?

Comment: as i understood only the "managed role" will be able to import fonts and other things and yes they want it, so somehow i need to make it work :) @ControlAltDel

Comment: Which browser? `document.fonts.add()` exists in latest Chrome browser.